# How to format embedded if statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What would be the best way to format this code? It looks a bit messy to me in regards to indentation etc.

```
 if (typeof _srwc != 'undefined') {
    for (var i=0; i < _srwc.length; i++){
         var currentArg = _srwc[i];;        
          if (typeof window[currentArg[0]] == 'function') {
             window[currentArg[0]](currentArg[1], currentArg[2], currentArg[3]);
             } else {
             console.log('The Setter method: "' + currentArg[0] + '" is undefined');
             }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

How to format code is not really how CodeReview works ;)

- You are indenting with 2 and with 4 spaces, pick one, I advocate 2
- It is more common to compare `_srwc` to `undefined` itself
- `_srwc` is an unfortunate name, it conveys no meaning
- `window[currentArg[0]](currentArg[1], currentArg[2], currentArg[3]);` could use a comment block
- Do not use `console.log` in production code
- Also, read about [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), it allows you to call a function and pass an array of arguments so you don't have to be limited to 3 arguments.

  ```
  if (_srwc !== undefined) {
    for (var i=0; i < _srwc.length; i++){
      var currentArg = _srwc[i];
      if (typeof window[currentArg[0]] == 'function') {
        window[currentArg[0]](currentArg[1], currentArg[2], currentArg[3]);
      } else {
        console.log('The Setter method: "' + currentArg[0] + '" is undefined');
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: 2 spaces? Infidel! 4 spaces is the one true style for perfect legibility. Well, maybe we can compromise on three. And we can both agree that tabs are worse ;-)

Comment: Agreed on tabs!!

Comment: Philistines, the lot of you.  Tabs forever!!  :P

Comment: "It is more common to compare _srwc to undefined itself" <-- well, that's *actually* true, but note that on older environments `undefined` was overridable, so checking `typeof` is a better choice IMHO - also note that *common* isn't ever *better* :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [guard clauses](http://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/), consistent indentation, some spaces around the operators and remove the double semicolon. You could also extract out an explanatory variable for `currentArg[0]` (which would remove some duplication and describe its content).

```
if (typeof _srwc == 'undefined') {
    return;
}
for (var i = 0; i < _srwc.length; i++) {
     var currentArg = _srwc[i];
     // TODO: just guessing, you might have a better name
     var methodName = currentArg[0]; 
     if (typeof window[methodName] != 'function') {
         console.log('The Setter method: "' + methodName + '" is undefined');
         continue;
     }
     window[methodName](currentArg[1], currentArg[2], currentArg[3]);
}
```

I suppose its a function or it could be extracted out to a function. Otherwise, the `return` won't be appropriate at the beginning.

Comment: This could die without a `continue` in the `if (typeof window[currentArg[0]] != 'function') {` since you would be trying to execute `currentArg` without it being a function